# Json response to C# custom object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am making a call to Json webservice and getting following Json

```
{
    "Content": {
        "CallId": "345353-981b-41a8-a108-a5d6891a7987",
        "Detail": {
            "ConversationId": "345353-981b-41a8-a108-a5d6891a7987",
            "UserId": "d232ad07-3fb6-4ecd-85f7-1c41a8c43013",
            "Region": "beta.us",
            "GroupId": "CT-VIP",
            "WalletId": "d232ad07-3fb6-4ecd-85f7-1c41a8c43013",
            "TrunkId": "d232ad07-3fb6-4ecd-85f7-1c41a8c43013"
        },
        "CallService": {
            "Region": "beta.us",
            "Id": "764bac3af1d84c7db8fe49b2f76e64c0"
        }
    },
    "Status": "OK"
}
```

I am using following code to make request and get response:

```
public string MakeCallTrucnkCall(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Headers.Add("X-Client:" + "dfsdfs; dsfsdfsf; 151.1.1; 1");
        request.Headers.Add("X-Authenticator-Session:" + "code here");

        try
        {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                return reader.ReadToEnd();                 
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
            using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();

                // log errorText
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
```

In case of error, I get this response:

```
{
    "Status": "ERR",
    "Errors": [
        {
            "Code": "Err_Auth_NoInfo"
        }
    ]
}
```

This returns response which I am converting to string using reader.ReadToEnd. But I want to convert this response to my custom object. I read somewhere that I can use Javascript serializer class but what properties my class should have to be filled by this json ?

Do I need to have class like following ?

```
public class APIResponse{
public Content {get;set;}
public CallId {get;set;}
public ConversationId {get;set;}
public Detail {get;set;}
public UserId {get;set;}
public Region{get;set;}
}
```

or it will be different ? I am not sure how json maps to custom object and what properties should i have and how to get response in form on my custom object instead of string. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Your C# class should look like your JSON data :

```
public class APIResponse
{
    public APIContent Content { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class APIContent
{
    public string CallID { get; set; }
    public APIDetail Detail { get; set; }
    public APICallService CallService { get; set; }
}
```

...

Then you could deserialize :

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
APIResponse response = serializer.Deserialize<APIResponse>(request);
```